# Meaning of "My luck precedes me"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "My luck precedes me" in below paragraph?

Would you like to buy flowers? Yes, how about the red rose. Sure, there you go sir. Thank You. As soon as he touched the roses, the flowers immediately withered. I should I have known. Hey, nothing, just a little sprinkle of water. Give it to me. As soon as she touched it, the flowers immediately blossomed again. Oh no. Not again. Give it to me. Here you go. Oh, you know just let it be. I don't deserve flowers. My luck precedes me.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIhQCow8CIo
Above line starts at 7:47

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simply poor English, perhaps a translation of a phrase in some other language, or a faulty adaptation of the idiom "your reputation precedes you"

The idiom "your reputation precedes you" means that people already know about you and the things you have done before you arrive. You might say it to a new colleague who you have heard about. "Hello John, I'm very excited that you are joining this team.  Your reputation as a problem solver and creative thinker precedes you".

It could mean "my bad luck affects things even before I arrive", but here it seems to be intended to mean "I'm very unlucky".  However, it is not a common saying in English.

There are other examples of strange English,  for example "Mr Wish's face turned gloom"  (should be "gloomy")